# Existence of continuous bijective function $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1] $ ? Continuous and only injective and continuous and olny surjective?

Tags: analysis, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

Does there exist any continuous bijective function $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1] $ , where $[0,1]$ is equipped with usual Euclidean metric of $\mathbb R$ and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is equipped with the usual Euclidean metric of $\mathbb R^2$ ? What if we require the continuous  mapping to be only injective or only surjective ?

Comment: Only surjective is pretty easy, just take the projection in one of the coordinates.

Comment: @GEdgar continuous and injective should be "No" due to [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), right? (restrict to $(0,1)^2$ first, such that the theorem applies). Or by [GTET](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/6359/1269) such a continuous injective map would be a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @Léo : yeah I figured out the surjective one.

Comment: In order: No.  No, yes.  (Corrected, thanks to kahen.)

Comment: @kahen , GEdgar : Can you please give the proofs of the first two . I see that proving the non-existence of injective continuous function is enough , but I don't know invariance of domain and am not willing to apply it . Thanks

Comment: Hint:  if $f$ is continuous and injective from compact space to Hausdorff space, then the inverse map is also continuous.

Comment: Hint: removing finitely many points from $[0,1]^2$ leaves a connected space.

Comment: @GEdgar  : But any metric space is Hausdorff ;  are you saying that any continuous injective map from a compact metric space to a metric space has continuous inverse ?

Comment: @SaunDev: Yes.  See if you can prove it.

Comment: @GEdgar : Yeah , I have been able to prove it , but how do I apply it here ?

Answer (score 2):

There does not exist a continuous bijective function $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1]$. Suppose such function exist. Consider the set $A= ([0,1] \times [0,1]) \setminus f^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$(Instead of $\frac{1}{2}$ you can take any point in the interior of $[-1,1]$). Then the function $f$ restricted to $A$ is also continuous. It is easy to see that $A$ is connected, but $f(A)$ is not connected. Since continuous image of connected set is connected, thus there does not exist such function. Now image of the injective continuous function is a non-degenerate interval in $[-1, 1]$ (it is  continuous image of a connected set). Take any interior point in that interval and argue as above.